# Homotopy fiber of the wedge of maps

Tags: homotopy-theory

Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be a map, and let $F$ be its homotopy fiber.

Then what is the homotopy fiber of the map $X \vee X \xrightarrow{f \, \vee f} Y \vee Y$?

In fact, I'm actually interested in the particular case $X=\mathbb C P^1$, $Y=\mathbb C P^{\infty}$, $f$ is the natural inclusion, and then, I think, $F=S^3$.

Comment: Since you are mixing limits with colimits, there probably is no simple answer. Since the maps from the wedges to the products in your example are $3$-connected, the map from $S^3\vee S^3$ to the fiber is $3$-connected, in particular the fiber can't be $S^3$. You can in principle determine its rational homotopy type as the derived kernel of the map between dgla models for the spaces; again, I don't see why the answer should be particularly nice.

Comment: If you want to compute the cohomology of the fiber, you should use the Eilenberg-Moore spectral sequence $Tor_{H^*(B)}(H^*(E),\mathbb Z)\Rightarrow H^*(F)$. This should be computable in your particular case, even integrally. For any particular $X$, $Y$, it is probably the way to go, but not necessarily tractable and there is probably not much you can say that is generally true about the fiber of the wedge in terms of original fiber. . . 
Bertram seems to be alluding to the Blakers-Massey theorem. You should look up the higher Blakers-Massey theorem, which may be able to get more information.

Comment: Here is a perspective that I think is useful to organize some theorems, but I present it mainly to suggest that the problem is difficult: Consider the case of classifying spaces of groups where $F\to X\to Y$ is $BK\to BG\to BQ$. Then the question is what is the kernel $G*G\to Q*Q$. The answer is not so nice. And since the homotopy category of pointed connected spaces is equivalent to the homotopy category of topological groups, similar things are true in general. In particular, filtering by word length is useful. This gives rise things like the James construction and the Hilton-Milnor theorem.